# Firefox WebExtension importing Services

Tags: javascript, firefox, firefox-addon, firefox-addon-webextensions

I am feeling overwhelmed by so many different approaches, guides, and yet none I tried work for me. Please connect at least some of the dots for me...

My objective is to find a window object in background script of Firefox WebExtension.

Problem, I cannot import `Services` library to use it for finding a `window` object.

Two methods I tried:

1. `Components.utils.import("resource://gre/modules/Services.jsm");` Gives a warning that `Components` is depricated, and an error: `Components.utils` is undefined.
2. `const { Cu } = require("chrome");
   let Services = Cu.import("resource://gre/modules/Services.jsm");` Throws an error that `require` is undefined.

That is a background script, point me to the right direction how to import the proper libraries/interfaces I need to work with?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The [MDN top level page for addons](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Add-ons$revision/1141081) used to give an overview over the different extension types (since FF57 only webextensions are supported).

> Components.utils.import

this is for restartless/XUL (legacy) extensions.

> const { Cu } = require("chrome");

this is for SDK extensions.

Neither will work in webextensions.

Unlike the other extension types webextensions are restrictive, they do not provide access to the low-level APIs that you can find all over the wiki.

So stick to pages that are under the [webextensions hierarchy](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Add-ons/WebExtensions) or standard web APIs when you're looking for documentation related to this extension type.